# APE (Ajax Push Engine) Does APE-Server processes the push requests synchronously or asynchronously

Tags: comet, ape

I am using APE (Ajax Push Engine) at my application. The connection between the application and the ape-server is inline push. And I am using APE only to broadcast messages to the clients. I.e. the clients do not send messages to the application or to each other.

My question is: Does APE-Server processes the push requests synchronously or asynchronously. 
I.e. if I send a message to push over APE-Server,

1. does APE-Server responses immediately to the application, and after that it pushes the messages to the clients? (asynchronously)  OR
2. does APE-Server responses to the application after it has pushed the messages to the clients (synchronously)

I am asking this, because sometimes responses from APE-Server to the application last to long (sometimes over 1 minute).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From what I know of Ajax in general is that it is asynchronous, so I would suspect APE is asynchronous as well.

Comment: that was not my question. I ment APE Server. And the connection between APE Server and application has nothing to do with ajax.

Comment: I suspect it has everything to do with Ajax (Ajax Push Engine, it's even in the name). But I can be wrong...

Answer (score 0):

The connection type is asychronous as you embed the server logic in webserver and ape communicates using http with the webserver (**client** <-> **APE** <-> **web server**)